# Why is my PHP header() redirecting prematurely?

Tags: php, arrays, redirect, filter

I am learning PHP by coding along with a tutorial, but modeling what I learn to fit my project where I am creating a simple page in which users can submit text which will be outputted to index.php.

Currently, my code (from post.php) automatically redirects to index.php upon loading.  When I disable the 'check for errors' section of the code, post.php does not redirect.  My intention is for the page to redirect to index.php AFTER the user fills out and submits the form.

What is wrong with my 'check for errors' section of the code?

```
<?php 

include('head.php');
include('header.php');  

$userQuote = '';
$errorsPost = array('user_message'=>'');

if(isset($_POST['submit-post'])){
    //check user quote
    if(empty($_POST['user_message'])):
        $errorsPost['user_message'] = 'You forgot to enter your message!  Try posting again. <br />';
    else:
        $userQuote = $_POST['user_message'];
    endif;
}
//end of post check

//check for errors
if(array_filter($errorsPost)):
    // echo 'errors in the form';
else:
    // echo 'form is valid';
    header('Location: index.php');
endif;

?>

<div class="container-post" id="post">
    <div class="container-post-form">

        <form action="index.php" method="POST">

            <textarea name="user_message" value="<?php echo h($userQuote) ?>" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Example: I don't want my cat Mazzy anymore.  Does anybody want her?  She likes to lick skin and it hurts." maxlength="560"></textarea>

            <ul class="container-form-buttons">
                <li>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit-post" value="submit-post" class="btn">Submit</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="btn">Close</button>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>


        <div class="red-text header-error"><?php echo $errorsPost['user_message']; ?></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your error checker _inside_ the post check block, at the end? I assume the redirect should only happen if the form is already submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that checks that the form is valid and redirects should be inside the `if (isset($_POST['submit-form']))` block. Otherwise it will run when the user is loading the page before submitting the form, and it will redirect.

```
<?php 

include('head.php');
include('header.php');  

$userQuote = '';
$errorsPost = array('user_message'=>'');

if(isset($_POST['submit-post'])){
    //check user quote
    if(empty($_POST['user_message'])):
        $errorsPost['user_message'] = 'You forgot to enter your message!  Try posting again. <br />';
    else:
        $userQuote = $_POST['user_message'];
    endif;
//check for errors
    if(array_filter($errorsPost)):
        // echo 'errors in the form';
    else:
        // echo 'form is valid';
        header('Location: index.php');
    endif;
}
//end of post check
?>
```